# Dijit ComboButton / DropDownMenu onclick misunderstanding

Tags: javascript, dojo, dom-events

I've just begun to play around with Dojo.  I simply wanted to display a dialog when an item in a Dijit ComboButton's DropDownMenu is clicked. I tried using dojo.connect to associate the onclick event with a function which would simply display a dialog with the text contained in the item, with no luck.

I've managed to get it working in a horrible way.  All the work is now actually written to the onclick attribute manually.  I'm clearly misunderstanding something here.  This is what I currently have:

#### JS:

```
    require(["dijit/form/Button", "dijit/form/FilteringSelect", "dijit/DropDownMenu", "dijit/MenuItem"]);

    //if the following is defined inside dojo.ready, nothing happens
    function getmail(text)
    {
         alert('No mail from '+text);
    }


    dojo.ready(function(){ 
        //the following does nothing:
        dojo.connect(dojo.query(".dijitMenuItemLabel"), "onclick", function(evt) {
            console.log("mail item clicked");
            alert('Blah');
            //dojo.stopEvent(evt);
        });
    });
```

#### HTML:

```
<form method="POST">

    <div data-dojo-type="dijit.form.ComboButton" id="getmail">

        <span>Get All Mail</span>

        <div data-dojo-type="dijit.DropDownMenu">

            <div data-dojo-type="dijit.MenuItem" 
                data-dojo-props="onClick:function(){getmail(dojo.trim(dojo.query('.dijitMenuItemLabel', this.domNode)[0].innerHTML))}">
                Yahoo</div> 

            <div data-dojo-type="dijit.MenuItem">Google</div>

        </div>

    </div>

</form>
```

---

### What does it look like I am clearly misunderstanding about Dojo?

(Or maybe I'm making simple JavaScript mistakes)

---

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c5Fa8/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it with something like

```
var myButton = dijit.byId('getmail');
myButton.on('click', function(){ alert('clicked') });
```

My guess is that you confused dojo.byId and dijit.byId when you fetched your button - regular DOM nodes work when you conenct a lowercase 'onclick' but widgets fire a camel case 'onClick' event (the distinction is because dijits fire with some keyboard events, for accessibility).

However, for newer versions of Dojo it is probably best to stay away from dojo.connect and instead just use simpler ".on" API I showed.

---

Ah, and before I forget, it also looks like you could have forgotten to run the Dojo parser (or set parseOnLoad to true) so the button was never created. Can you provide a fully executable example on JSFiddle?

Comment: `parseOnLoad` is set to `true`.  The code you gave certainly does work as you said but what I'm looking to do is detect when the items in the downdown menu are clicked.  The real questions are why does the `getmail` function have to be outside `dojo.ready` and why does all the work have to be hardcoded to the `onclick` attribute instead of existing only once in `getmail()`? JSFiddle added to the question

Comment: @AdamLynch: Well, you can surely call getmail from inside the onclick or pass getmail as the onclick handler. Are you sure its not a simple scoping issue? Remember that Javascript variables (and functions) are only visible inside the function where they were defined.

Comment: Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv73d/1/) doesn't work.  I've tried a lot of similar implementations

Comment: @AdamLynch: `onClick:function(){getmail(this)}` will only work if getmail is a global function. Since you defined getmail inside another function that is not the case.

Comment: how can I pass getmail as the handler then like you said?